# Move to specific record in TFDQuery with primary key

Tags: delphi

### Question

I am wondering if there is any way I can move to a specific record in a DataSet (FDQuery) by knowing only the Primary Key of the table.

### What I know

I know I can move to the next/prior record by using `FDQuery.Next; FDQuery.Prior;` or move to a specific record number using `FDQuery.RecNo := 2`.

In my case, I just know the Primary Key (id) of the item and I want to move to this specific record that has the same id as mine.

To make it clear I can achieve this by iterating through the records, however, I would like to know if the is a way to move directly to the record, without needing to iterate through all the records.

```
with FDQuery do
begin
  First;
  while not Eof do
  begin
    if FieldByName(C_ID).AsInteger = IDAsPrimaryKey then
      // Found!
      Break;
    Next;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use the `Locate` boolean function, as in

```
   if FDQuery.Locate(C_ID, IDAsPrimaryKey, []) then
     // do whatever
```

See e.g. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_Locate for more info.

Note that `Locate` will accept a `;`-separated list of field names as the first argument.  In that case, the second argument needs to be a variant array of field values, which you can construct at run-time using the `VarArrayOf` function.

Btw, `Locate` is defined in the `TDataSet` class, but it is up to the authors of a given descendant library like FireDAC whether and how it is implemented in specific component classes.

You could also use the `GoToKey` or `FindKey` methods - see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Executing_a_Search_with_Goto_Methods.  You may find one or other of these to be quicker than `Locate`, especially if your dataset already has a client-side index on the primary key but `Locate` is generally more convenient and concise, because the others are more long-winded to use.

Comment: You are always saving my life with delphi. I found something about locate before but couldn't find exactly how to use it. You explained in detail. Thanks!